# Facebook FQL / Graph API: Instagram & Foursquare posts do not show up, even though permissions for Open Graph actions are ok

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm running into a bit of an issue with the Facebook Graph API / Facebook FQL.  Let me start out with some background information: I ran into an issue in which a bunch of albums would not contain any pictures when they were requested through the graph API, like Instagram or Foursquare albums.

There's actually an issue related to this logged on the FB bug tracking system: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/202119973248747?browse=search_50f96e47a936c5060070555

From the comments on that page, I reached a related issue on StackExchange: [Posts from Instagram not showing up on Facebook Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677898/posts-from-instagram-not-showing-up-on-facebook-open-graph-api) => in this post, a solution to the issue at hand is provided by Igy: by specifically asking the user permission for the open graph (own & friend) actions of a specific app, the albums should contain pictures.

Sure enough, that works.  So far, so good.  But this is where my issue starts: I've now asked the correct permissions to the user of my app, and pictures appear in Open Graph albums (like the Instagram, Foursquare, ... albums). However, the related posts in the feed do not seem to appear: if I go to a friend's timeline (ask for his feed connection through the Graph API) , the Instagram / Foursquare posts are not returned.  I'm a bit a loss here, because sure enough: the pictures do appear in the albums, it's simply the related posts that seem to be missing, both in the newsfeed & on someone's timeline.  What's going on here?  Am I missing permissions?  Is this simply impossible?

Related to this: I can now specifically ask for the related open graph permissions to be able to view pictures in an album.  But: is there any way to know which app created an album, or another way to know which app-specific permissions to ask from the user?  Without that, it's impossible to solve issues like this for future and/or not-hard-coded apps: eg: I can ask for permission for Foursquare & Instagram because I hard-coded those namespaces, but if I run into another album by another app which also uses the open graph to publish pictures to it, I have no way of knowing which app created the album, which leads to not knowing what app to ask permissions for to be able to view the pictures... Any clue if this can be done?