# How to get Likes of Instagram photo posts in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph, instagram

I am developing an app that processes `<used_id>/posts` connection to read the posts a user have made and count the likes and comments that have been received.

Yesterday I noticed that Instagram photo posts do not appear in posts connection. After a little search I found this [Posts from Instagram not showing up on Facebook Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677898/posts-from-instagram-not-showing-up-on-facebook-open-graph-api) after which I was able to see Instagram photos in Feed connection if permission user_actions:instapp was added (or friends_actions:instapp for friend posts).

**But two problems remain:**

1) The posts still do not appear in Posts connection, which is more convenient for usage in my case because I am not interested in Posts of other users which may appear in Feed.

2) Even if I use Feed connection the posts do not have Likes field filled, does not matter whether I specify it directly or not. I assume that the same goes with Comments. Therefore in my case Feed is also useless because I need Likes data.

The only solution that works is by using `<user_id>/instapp:take` - there I get all photos also with Likes. So I might use it, but the trouble is - then I need to do double API call, because Instagram posts are not the only in which I am interested in (I still need to call `<user_id>/posts`).

I have submitted this bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/131821543664928

Perhaps someone has an idea for a better solution than calling instapp:take?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered doing batch API calls? Requesting both endpoints in a single batch call. FB blog post at: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/17/batch-requests-in-graph-api/

Comment: Yes, batch call is the way I would do it if going the "instapp:take" route for a single user. But the thing is I am already doing batch API calls for multiple users' Posts connection i.e. requesting posts of multiple app user friends. So still the API call count (and waiting time) doubles.