# How can I find the application that posted a Facebook photo via Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that pulls in content from both Facebook and Instagram, but users frequently cross-post the same photo. Using the Facebook Graph API, I'm trying to find a way to determine if any given photo was posted via Instagram.

I'm confident that this data exists, but I don't know how to access it via the API. Looking at one of my own cross-posted photos, I know Facebook at least has the data:

[image]

Comment: What data do you get when you retrieve the post via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two solutions.

1. We only were asking for user_photo and user_status permissions. If we had asked for read_stream, we could have looked at the /me/posts endpoint, which offers the `application` field. We might do this, but the permissions could be confusing for users since it also allows us to read their newsfeed. Ideally, there'd be a user_posts permission that just gave us access to everything the user posts, but nothing posted by their friends.
2. Every Instagram photo shared is put into the same Facebook album. So, we just check to see if a photo is put in that album and disregard it if they've also authenticated with Instagram in our application. It feels less reliable, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the similar questions

- [How to get Likes of Instagram photo posts in Facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334601/how-to-get-likes-of-instagram-photo-posts-in-facebook-graph-api)
- [Posts from Instagram not showing up on Facebook Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677898/posts-from-instagram-not-showing-up-on-facebook-open-graph-api)
- And the bug report at FB: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/110563582419837/

You could query the "Instagram Photos" album with FQL:

```
select pid, images from photo where album_object_id in (select object_id from album where owner = me() and name='Instagram Photos')
```